# Creating nested dictionary from text file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, collections

I have a text file of thousands of blocks like this. For processing I needed to convert it into dictionary.

Text file Pattern

```
[conn.abc]
domain = abc.com
id = Mike
token = jkjkhjksdhfkjshdfhsd

[conn.def]
domain = efg.com
id = Tom
token = hkjhjksdhfks

[conn.ghe]
domain = ghe.com
id = Jef
token = hkjhadkjhskhfskdj7979
```

Another sample data

```
New York 
domain = Basiclink.com 
token = eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL21zLmNvbS9zbm93 
method = http 
username = abc@comp.com 

Toronto 
domain = hollywoodlink.com 
token = eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL21zLmNvbS9zbm93Zmxha2UvsfdsdcHJvZGJjcy1lYXN0LXVzLTIiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC9lMjliODE 
method = http 
username = abc@comp.com
```

Would like to convert it into following.

```
d1={conn.abc:{'domain':'abc.com','id': 'Mike',token:'jkjkhjksdhfkjshdfhsd'}
 conn.def:{'domain':'efg.com', 'id': 'Tom',token:'hkjhjksdhfks'}
 conn.ghe:{'domain':'ghe.com', 'id': 'Jef',token:'hkjhadkjhskhfskdj7979'}}
```

Thanks

Comment: does every set have 4 rows. Is it consistent?

Comment: Yes Joe indeed. I am actually cleaning the file to make of this pattern.

Comment: Python and regex should be able to handle most of the conditions for you. If this is a clean pattern of 4 rows then space with each row having a similar pattern, then the solution is very simple.

Comment: btw, d1 does not have keys. It looks like a dictionary and it looks like a string. Did you by any chance mean to say `d1={conn.abc: {'domain':'abc.com','id': 'Mike',`token`:'jkjkhjksdhfkjshdfhsd'}`. Note here that i put a `:` after `conn.abc` and also made `token` a string instead of a variable. Let me know if these are correct assumptions to make

Comment: Yes Joe , Your assumption was indeed correct. I made the changes in the above output. I will try to implement your solution anyways.

Comment: Indeed rows are 4 only and each separated by new line. But I am getting errro "need more than 1 value to unpack" The real sample is like below

Comment: Do you have any row which does not have `key = value`, instead it is just a string (other than the `[key]` line. ?

Comment: please add this in the question section. The comments section does not format it correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230345/discussion-between-joe-ferndz-and-asrar).

Comment: I just added again. If you can check.

Comment: Joe I checked It happens due to long brackets..

Comment: Will the data have both `[conn.abc]` and `New York` as keys?

Comment: No it is only one . New York comes after cleaning. I can keep it in brackets also. I actually tweaked it a bit and think I am almost at my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input file can have varying # of lines with data, this code should work.

Assumptions:

1. Each key (eg: `conn.abc`) will start with open square bracket and end with open square bracket. example `[conn.abc]`
2. Each inner dictionary key value will be separated by `=`

If the key value can either be `[key]` or `key`, then use the below line of code instead of the commented line of code.

```
    elif '=' not in line:
    #elif line[0] == '[' and line[-1] == ']':
```

Code for this is:

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as f:
    d1 = {}
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '': continue
        elif line[0] == '[' and line[-1] == ']':
            if i !=0: d1[dkey]= dtemp
            dkey = line[1:-1]
            dtemp = {}
        else:
            line_key,line_value = line.split('=')
            dtemp[line_key.strip()] = line_value.strip()
    d1[dkey]=dtemp

print (d1)
```

If the input file is:

```
[conn.abc]
domain = abc.com
id = Mike
token = jkjkhjksdhfkjshdfhsd

[conn.def]
domain = efg.com
id = Tom
dummy = Test
token = hkjhjksdhfks

[conn.ghe]
domain = ghe.com
id = Jef
token = hkjhadkjhskhfskdj7979
```

The output will be as follows:

```
{'conn.abc': {'domain': 'abc.com', 'id': 'Mike', 'token': 'jkjkhjksdhfkjshdfhsd'}, 
 'conn.def': {'domain': 'efg.com', 'id': 'Tom', 'dummy': 'Test', 'token': 'hkjhjksdhfks'}, 
 'conn.ghe': {'domain': 'ghe.com', 'id': 'Jef', 'token': 'hkjhadkjhskhfskdj7979'}}
```

Note here that I added `dummy = Test` as a key value for `conn.def`. So your output will have that additional key:value in the output.

Comment: Thanks Joe for helping out. The issue is my token size will vary and can go beyond many lines.

Comment: Before I wrote the code, I did ask if the lines in the file was constant. What are the variations. Should I consider every time we have a line starting with `[key_value]`, its a new set until a blank line?

Comment: @Asrar, updated the code to address variations. Also added a dummy key value to show you that the code is flexible enough to handle variations

Comment: Appreciate your help Joe. Fyi I have posted real sample data for two blocks. I will try updated version

Comment: unable to see updated data in the question section

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("name_of_your_file.txt")
```

Then you can work with `config` as standard dictionary:

```
for name_of_section, section in config.items():
    for name_of_value, val in section.items():
        print(name_of_section, name_of_value, val)
```

Prints:

```
conn.abc domain abc.com
conn.abc id Mike
conn.abc token jkjkhjksdhfkjshdfhsd
conn.def domain efg.com
conn.def id Tom
conn.def token hkjhjksdhfks
conn.ghe domain ghe.com
conn.ghe id Jef
conn.ghe token hkjhadkjhskhfskdj7979
```

Or:

```
print(config["conn.abc"]["domain"])
```

Prints:

```
abc.com
```